# Average of BLEU scores on two subsets of data is not the same as overall score

Tags: metrics, evaluation, seq2seq, bleu

For evaluating a sequence generation model, I'm using BLEU1:BLEU4. I separated the test set to two sets and calculated the scores on each set separately, as well as, on the whole test set. Surprisingly, the results I get from the whole test set is not the weighted average of the results I get from each set. For example, consider the BLEU4 scores I get on a set and two subsets of it:

**set1, 866 elements**: 0.0001529267908

**set2, 1010 elements**: 0.1625387989

**<set1,set2>, 1876 elements**: 0.3063472152

How should I aggregate the results on two subsets to get the overall result?

Note: I know that all the elements in set1 are shorter than 4 tokens that's why BLEU4 is almost zero there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BLEU score is by definition non-linear. As you can see in the original paper by [Papineni et al.](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P02-1040.pdf):

[image]

It is a product of two terms: brevity penalty (BP) and a harmonic mean of *n*-gram precisions. Both the brevity penalty and the harmonic mean are not linear operations with respect to averaging.

Regarding what you should report: since the two tests set look fundamentally different, the best option is to report two separate numbers.

I don't know what your task is, but given that the desired outputs are very short, BLEU might not be the best choice for evaluation.  You might consider something edit-based (e.g., TER) or even plain accuracy might do a good job.